# How to select the next 50 records from a specified row in an SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

Consider that my SQLite table has the following schema,

```
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

| unique_id(TXT) | object_data(BLOB) |

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

|                |                   |

|                |                   |

|                |                   |

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Assume that the row_id property is enabled, and so my question is, for a given unique_id, is it possible to fetch the next 50 records from the table,
using a single SQL query? (Using the row_id property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting result through this method.

```
Select * from table_name [WHERE conditions] Limit 50 offset (Select row_id from table_name where unique_id = x);
```